# Initialize .mask on future selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, initialization

Need to initialize .mask('999/9999/999') on future selector after i .append() selector by jquery.
I tried:

```
$('body').delegate(selector, 'mask', '999/9999/999');
```

but it does not work. Maybe somebody can help me to level up my skill :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `selector` is a string that finds the added input element, just do this after appending:

```
$(selector).mask('999/9999/999');
```

Comment: i have one selector before: $('input[name="phone[]"]').mask('+37(999)999-99-99'); after i click add phone, it append one more selector. and this construction works only at that one which was before append

Comment: Can you show the function that appends another element? Initialization should happen in or after this function.

Comment: i solved it by adding .mask just after .append function in click event but if it is no event how to initialize such plugins. for example if i will add 10+ html constructions to DOM and need to initialize 10+ plugins. i need to start function with these all init in event, that will add data?

Comment: and one more difficult example. .autocomplete with _render = function. In this function i need also to use plugin. How to?

Comment: That's right, you need to initialize it for every element that gets created dynamically. I am not sure if you need to reinitialize it in combination with autocomplete, that should only be needed if the autocomplete render function replaces the input completely, but not if it only changes by the value.

Comment: yeah. autocomplete replaces input completely.

Comment: .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

      return $( '<li>' )
        .append( '<a href="/'+item.type+'/'+item.id+'">' + item.value +'  </a>' )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

Comment: If you are using autocomplete from jQuery UI, it should not replace the element completely, but only `manipulates its element's value programmatically`. Try to initialize it like `$(...).autocomplete(...).mask(...)` in the place where you add and append the new element.

Comment: i tried but  
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem ={}; construction how to add .mask after this